# WP taxonomy used with custom-post type breaks my statics pages permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I'm having a hard time setuping my WP.

My structure peramink is this one :

game/taxonomy-slug/postname

To do so, i use the plugin UltimateCMS.

I've made my custom post type name "game" who's configured like this:

rewrite : true,
slug : game/%games%,
width tront : true,
feed : true,
page : true,
hierarchical : false

And my taxonomy is named "games" and is configured like this:

hierarchical : false,
rewrite : true,
slug : %games%,
width tront : false

Oh and I also use this in my function file :

```
add_filter('post_link', 'rating_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'rating_permalink', 10, 3);

function rating_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%games%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

        // Get post
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if (!$post) return $permalink;

        // Get taxonomy terms
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'games');  
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        else $taxonomy_slug = 'autres';

    return str_replace('%games%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

I currently have the URLs that i want whith this but the thing is that this taxonomy break my statics pages.
I have a page (url: /web-tv/) that does not work anymore. If I desactivate my "games" taxonomy it does work again.

The weird thing is that my /web-tv/ page can work if I make its URL go on a 3rd level like this : /info/toto/web-tv/

I tried everything in my skills but i can't find any solution.

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: I tried to refresh permalinks by submiting modifications but it does not work.

Comment: I am stuck in the same problem. How did you resolve the issue? All of my page links are broken

Comment: I know it's an old question, but did you solve this? I'm stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used in post type slug 'game/%games%'
and in taxonomy slug 'game'

And it solved the problem.

Make sure you have a slug in your taxonomy.